# Use custom CSS template in combination with Primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a project which is developed by Primefaces 2.2 and JSF 2.1.

Since I am not satisfied with Primefaces' template neither ThemeRoller that they provide, I found very interesting themes on

http://themeforest.net

and I want to integrate one of those in my project.

Is it possible to integrate Primefaces with templates from Themeforest? Are there any traps that I need to consider?

Answer (score 0):

Primefaces themes are powered by theme rollers, (separate css for structure and skinning). the only way of implementing themes is by using Primefaces's template or ThemeRoller. Or else you can try dynamic themes by defining EL expression as a param value

```
  <context-param>
  <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
  <param-value>#{themeSwitcherBean.theme}</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

as mentioned in primefaces document here http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course, but it's not a template. It's a theme. You can do that easily with facalet.

Comment: Could you be more specific? How facelets can help me?

Answer (score -1):

I never use the template / skinning provided by Primefaces, but sometimes integrate it in the project because there are some very useful components. Of course you can use a custom template like those you saw on Themeforest. All you have to do is create `XHMTL` instead of `HTML` files and correct some syntax (for example `input` tags need a closing tag in `XHTML`). The problem is you can't completely disable the styling of components like the `p:inputText`, you have to use `h:inputText` and then apply the classes provided by your template in the `styleClass` attribute.